# xsl:call-template - Binding results between two template calls

Tags: xslt

I have a call to a template, and that template will return a css class name depending on the value that I send as a parameter. For the sake of this example, let's say that the parameter is the sum of an element that we're processing. Let's also assume that the css specifies a blue background if the sum is greater than 10 (class "blue") and a yellow background if the sum is less or equal than 10 (class "yellow").

```
        <xsl:call-template name="template1">
            <xsl:with-param name="param" select="sum(.//something)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
```

I would like, in a different call, to use this css class name, depending on what was returned from the call to "template1". So I would like the following element to be of either the "yellow" or "blue" class, depending on what was returned on the previous call.

```
        <xsl:call-template name="template2">
             <xsl:with-param name="param" select=".//something"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
```

Is this possible to achieve in xslt? Or is there a better way to do this? Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can store a result in a variable with

```
<xsl:variable name="cssClass">
        <xsl:call-template name="template1">
            <xsl:with-param name="param" select="sum(.//something)"/>
        </xsl:call-template> 
</xsl:variable>
```

then elsewhere you can reference that variable with e.g. `<xsl:with-param name="param" select="$className"/>`.

Comment: The thing is, one select should use sum(something) and the other select something else. So the select values are different, but the css class should be the same.

Comment: You might want to show us the XML input you have and the corresponding output you want to create with XSLT and show more of your XSLT. It is not clear when and where you want to use the computed CSS class value, whether you want to build some intermediary result you transform further.